# Graficar en Highcfarts con 2 Ejes

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Quiero poder gráficar dos o mas categorías (series) en un solo gráfico con magnitudes muy diferentes, para esto se que se requiere 2 ejes Y, por ejemplo que en la parte izquierda haya una escala de hasta 100 y en parte derecha una escala de 20, he visto la documentación de highcharts y no puedo plasmar lo que quiero.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline'
   },

    title: {
      text: 'Informe Mensual'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Ventas Vs No. Productos'
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
         text: 'Valores en Millones'
      }
    },

    xAxis: {
      categories: ['DIA 1','DIA 2','DIA 3','DIA 4','DIA 5','DIA 6','DIA 
7','DIA 8','DIA 9','DIA 10','DIA 11','DIA 12','DIA 13','DIA 14','DIA 
15','DIA 16','DIA 17','DIA 18','DIA 19','DIA 20','DIA 21','DIA 22','DIA 
23','DIA 24','DIA 25','DIA 26','DIA 27','DIA 28', 'DIA 29', 'DIA 30', 'DIA 
31']
},

    series: [{
      name : "Ventas",
      data: []

    },{
      name : "No. Productos",
      data: []
    }]
  });

    $( "#MES" ).change(function() {
    //validamos las fechass
    var ANO = $('#ANO').val();
    var MES = $('#MES').val();
    var CIUDAD = $('#CIUDAD').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "procesar.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: { ANO: ANO, MES: MES, CIUDAD: CIUDAD },
      dataType: "json"
    })

    .done(function(data) {

      console.log(CIUDAD);
      console.log(ANO);
      console.log(MES);
      console.log(data);

      chart.series[0].setData(data[0]); 
      chart.series[1].setData(data[1]);  
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo necesitas agregar un identificador de eje diferente para cada uno como [propiedad `yAxis` en `series`](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes) y automáticamente elegirá una escala adecuada e independiente (diferente una de otra si es necesario) para cada eje:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
     renderTo: 'container',
     type: 'spline'
 },

 title: {
   text: 'Informe Mensual'
 },
 subtitle: {
     text: 'Ventas Vs No. Productos'
 },

 yAxis: {
   title: {
      text: 'Valores en Millones'
   }
 },

 xAxis: {
    categories: ['DIA 1','DIA 2','DIA 3','DIA 4','DIA 5','DIA 6',
      'DIA 7','DIA 8','DIA 9','DIA 10','DIA 11','DIA 12','DIA 13','DIA 14',
      'DIA 15','DIA 16','DIA 17','DIA 18','DIA 19','DIA 20','DIA 21','DIA 22',
      'DIA 23','DIA 24','DIA 25','DIA 26','DIA 27','DIA 28', 'DIA 29', 'DIA 30', 'DIA 31']
 },

 series: [{
    name : "Ventas",
    data: [],
    yAxis: 0,
 },{
    name : "No. Productos",
    data: [],
    yAxis: 1,
  }]
});
```